# Images are changed to different colors (with pillow), how to get it back to the original colors?

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, video-processing

I am trying to find the dominant color in a frame in a video. This works well, however, my frames are somehow converted into different colors. Yellow/pink becomes blue/purple-ish, but black and white stay the same (thus it is not the inverted colors).

Does anyone know where it comes from and how I can change it so that the original colors are kept? This is my code:

```
import cv2
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from collections import Counter
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

def show_blurred_image(image, dominant_color):
    frame_to_blur = Image.fromarray(image)
    
    blurred_frame = cv2.blur(image, (200,200))
    blurred_frame = Image.fromarray(blurred_frame)
    
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(frame_to_blur),plt.title('Original')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(blurred_frame),plt.title('Blurred')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

    
    R = round(dominant_color[0])
    G = round(dominant_color[1])
    B = round(dominant_color[2])

    custom_color = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (R, G, B)
    print(custom_color)
    rect = patches.Rectangle((1620,0),300,1080,linewidth=1,
                             fill = True,
                             edgecolor=custom_color,
                             facecolor=custom_color)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    
    plt.show()
    

def get_dominant_color(image, k=4, image_processing_size = None):
    """
    takes an image as input
    returns the dominant color of the image as a list
    
    dominant color is found by running k means on the 
    pixels & returning the centroid of the largest cluster

    processing time is sped up by working with a smaller image; 
    this resizing can be done with the image_processing_size param 
    which takes a tuple of image dims as input

    >>> get_dominant_color(my_image, k=4, image_processing_size = (25, 25))
    [56.2423442, 34.0834233, 70.1234123]
    """
    #resize image if new dims provided
    if image_processing_size is not None:
        image = cv2.resize(image, image_processing_size, 
                            interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
    #reshape the image to be a list of pixels
    image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))

    #cluster and assign labels to the pixels 
    clt = KMeans(n_clusters = k)
    labels = clt.fit_predict(image)

    #count labels to find most popular
    label_counts = Counter(labels)

    #subset out most popular centroid
    dominant_color = clt.cluster_centers_[label_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]]

    return list(dominant_color)

dominant_colors = []
show_frame = 10
frame_nb = 0

while(video.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = video.read()
    
    if ret == True: 
        if (frame_nb == show_frame):
            dominant_color = get_dominant_color(frame)
            show_blurred_image(frame, dominant_color)
    
        frame_nb += 1
    else:
        break
    
        
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: OpenCV by default loads images as BGR, while PIL expect RGB.

Comment: Thanks! This helped, I added one line below ret, frame = video.read():
```frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)``` and now to colors are correct, great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV loads images in a BGR format, while PIL and matplotlib works with the RGB format. If you want to use the libraries together, you need to convert the images in the right color spaces.

In your case :

```py
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```